# Is the pdf of chi-squared distribution increasing with smaller degrees of freedom?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference

Proposition:

Consider $W_k \sim \chi^2(r(k))$, and then we derive $$Pr(W_k < t) \geq Pr(W_{s_n} < t),$$

where $k$ and $s_n$ are the degrees of freedom, and $k \leq s_n$.

How to prove it?

Comment: There is something missing in the sentence "Then, the variation of the function $f(t)$ on $\left ( 0, +\infty  \right )$." The problem is not clear.

Comment: It might help to consider that $W_{n + m} = (Z_1^2 + \cdots + Z_n^2)+(Z_{n+1}^2 + \cdots + Z_{n+m}^2)$ $= W_n + W_n,$ where $Z_i \stackrel{iid}{\sim} Norm(0,1);$
$W_n \sim Chisq(n)$ and independently $W_m \sim Chisq(m).$ Also, $W_n > 0$ and $W_m > 0.$